# Angular Live Development Server failing to serve a blank new project

Tags: angularjs

I am learning `Angular` by following a basic tutorial.

I created and opened up a brand new project, changed absolutly nothing, and when I serve the project, I get the following errors:

[image]

Googling each error individually has brought up some suggestions that I have tried (e.g. re-installing npm, pting out of Ivy, serving again and again) to no avail...

All of my installs are fresh and the latest What am I missing?

**Errors' Text**:

Error: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.d.ts:44:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/platform-browser) which declares BrowserModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

44 export declare class BrowserModule

Error: node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2684:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppRoutingModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/router) which declares RouterModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

2684 export declare class RouterModule

Error: node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:2684:22 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of AppRoutingModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.
This likely means that the library (@angular/router) which declares RouterModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

2684 export declare class RouterModule

Error: src/app/app-routing.module.ts:10:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors
10 export class AppRoutingModule